# Filter inputs in custom ContentProvider functions

Tags: sql, android, android-contentprovider

In a custom `ContentProvider` I need to filter out some columns specified in the inputs. Given the text-oriented Android interfaces this is giving me a hard time.

For example the input on `MyContentProvider.query()` would effectively ask something like:

```
SELECT column_a, column_b FROM my_table WHERE column_a=1 AND column_b=red;
```

The problem is that at this particular `MyContentProvider` _column_b_ might not make any sense and would not be present in the table. Filtering the projection so that only relevant columns remain can be easily done since it's a String[]. However, filtering the String "`where`" (selection) and "`selectionArgs`" inputs for these columns is not trivial. If done properly it would become:

```
SELECT column_a FROM my_table WHERE column_a=1;
```

Otherwise one would get a `SQLiteException "no such column"`.

So, is there any **easy way to ignore or filter columns** from such an sql statement or do I need to go and write some smart albeit very limited regexp parsing code for the selection part?

The reason I'm not getting the right inputs is because I maintain a custom `ContentProvider` as an interface to address, but I talk to multiple custom `ContentProvider`s herein (in the background). One way or another, I would need to filter the selection somewhere.

Please note that I am not asking simply how to do a query or use the `SELECT ... WHERE` statement. However it concerns my implementation of the `query()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending your `MyContentProvider` with `ContentProvider` why don't you just overload the `query()` method?

Look at [ContentProvider - Sharing Content using the ContentProvider](http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/ContentProvider) for someone elses example on how to create a custom ContentProvider.  You should have full control over what data you fetch from your `SQLiteDatabase`.

More importantly, look at the [arguments provided](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) to `query()`, as they contain the information you need to you in a way where you can dynamically build the query from what is passed into the method call.

Depending on if you can find a good query builder, you have an opportunity to build a small but powerful abstraction layer to build your queries, so that you minimize the amount of actual SQL that you write yourself.

Also, always remember to sanitize your inputs!